# Unit testing some methods that aren't required by outside objects.

Tags: java, unit-testing, scope

I have my database layer:

```
public class DataBaseLayer
{
    public Result runQuery(Query q)
    {
        this.openSession(); 
        this.runPackage(q);
        Results r = this.fetchResults();
        this.closeSession();
        return r;
    }

}
```

Currently all those methods are private methods.

But I want to be able to test them.

for example

```
private void testOpenSession_wrongUserNamePassword_returnsBadUserNamePassWordError();
private void testrunPackage_insufficientPrivileges_returnsInsufficientPrivlegesError();
```

The question is what's the nicest way of doing this?

I figure I could either:

- Just test the runQuery method for bad username password etc.
- Make those methods protected.
- Make those methods public.

Comment: They're implementation details. Just test the exposed methods with the scenarios that you would test those private ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your class is using some collaborator to connect to the database when you call `this.openSession()` mock that collaborator and have the mock return the responses desired for bad password or insufficient privileges so you can test the behaviour of your class in that scenario. eg

class under test

```
public class DataBaseLayer {
    public DataBaseLayer(SomeDBClass dbObject){
        this.dbObject = dbObject;
    }

    ...

    private void openSession() {
        dbObject.connect(username, password);
    }

    ...

    public Result runQuery(Query q){
    ...
}
```

test class

```
public class DataBaseLayerTest {

    @Test(expected = IncorrectPasswordException.class)
    public void testOpenSession_wrongUserNamePassword_returnsBadUserNamePassWordError() {
        SomeDBClass someDBClass = Mockito.mock(SomeDBClass.class)
        Mockito.when(someDBClass.connect(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).throw(new IncorrectPasswordException())

        DataBaseLayer underTest = new DataBaseLayer(someDBClass)

        underTest.runQuery(someQuery);
    }
}
```